# how to add image to toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

I am very new at coding and I have been trying to figure out how to add an image to the toolbar in Android. Why doesn't this work?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.admin.prototypeapp.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

          <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/white_logo_transparent"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Is it possible to insert an image like this?

It is telling me that /android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar should be  /android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Rookie mistake? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xml tag of the `Toolbar` is not closed.Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/white_logo_transparent"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand how the ">" after colorPrimary doesn't close android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar, but thanks Alex Al.


 For those who might google this question in the future I changed the imageview height to 35dp to make it no take up the full screen.